# Unity3D - GameObject as a static function

Tags: unity, component-based, gameobject

Newbie Unity3D/C# developer here.
I've tried learning Unity3D during my May/June college vacation and came across a problem:
Code 1:

```
CameraObj returnVoid;

void Start () 
{
    returnVoid = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<CameraObj> ();
    returnVoid.ComponentType ();
}
```

Code 2:

```
GameObject returnDirectLight;

void Start () 
{
    returnDirectLight = GameObject.Find ("Directional Light");
    Debug.Log (returnDirectLight.GetComponent<DRLight>().directionString);
}
```

`CameraObj` is my custom component. 
As far as I know, `GetComponent` is actually a public method. I understand the logic behind Code 2. What I fail to understand is Code 1. How does `GetComponent` become a static function here? Does it become abstract in my `CameraObj` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not using GetComponent() on the class GameObject, it's using GetComponent() on the result of GameObject.Find()

GameObject.Find() is a static function, but it returns a specific object. Note that Code 2 is also using GameObject.Find() but then you store the result object in a variable. Code 1 uses the exact same functions but doesn't store the result of GameObject.Find() that's the only difference.

Comment: So why can't I use `returnDirectLight = GameObject.Find ("Directional Light").GetComponent<DRLight> ();` instead of using `returnDirectLight = GameObject.Find ("Directional Light");` in code 2? That's where my confusion lies

Comment: Because returnDirectLight is a gameObject, not a component. Make returnDirectLight a DRLight and it will work.

Comment: Additional clarification: a GameObject is a type of object that is simply a container for a bunch of components. GameObject.Find() returns a GameObject instance, not the components contained by that GameObject.